# Why is isascii() deprecated?

Tags: c++, c, ascii, posix, libc

According to the isascii() manpage:

http://linux.die.net/man/3/isascii

> POSIX.1-2008 marks isascii() as obsolete, noting that it cannot be
>   used portably in a localized application.

I'm not sure I see where the portability problem is. A very simple implementation of this function is:

```
int isascii(int ch) { return ch >= 0 && ch < 128; }
```

In which situations is the above implementation either not sufficient or not portable?

Thank you

Comment: @SaiyamDoshi: does this do anything different?

Comment: Whether that implementation is sufficient and portable depends on what you want to use this function for. What do you have in mind?

Comment: The function is definitely not portable to systems not using ASCII encoding for characters, like IBM mainframes.

Answer (score 7):

I suppose it would not work if you have a character encoding that does not use the low seven-bit range exclusively for ASCII. Probably happens in some multibyte encodings, when the given byte is only part of the character.

For example, in [Shift-JIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS), the second byte can start at 0x40, which overlaps with ASCII.
And even in the first byte, there are some slight alterations, such as 0x5C (currency symbol instead of backslash) or 0x7E (some sort of slash instead of tilde).

I found this [article](https://cs.au.dk/~sortie/sortix/release/0.8/doc/obsolete-stuff) where someone explained the reason behind the non-inclusion of POSIX functions in their own OS design:

> This function is rather pointless. If we use a character encoding that wasn't
>      ascii compatible, then it doesn't make sense. If we use a sane character
>      encoding such as UTF-8, then you can simply check if the value is at most 127.

Comment: i think he's asking for specific encoding in which it would be true, and i can't think of any.  the encodings that i know of overlap the initial 128 values.

Answer (score 3):

> In which situations is the above implementation either not sufficient or not portable?

When any EBCDIC character set is in use.

There are EBCDIC code pages where non-ASCII characters have a value between 0 and 127, for example the [SPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#SPS) character has value `0x09` in EBCDIC, but is not an ASCII character (it corresponds to the U+0085 Unicode code point which is encoded as 0xC2 0x85 in UTF-8, and is outside the ASCII range).

There are also ASCII characters that have a value greater than `127` in EBCDIC, such as **all the alphanumeric characters!** See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC#Code_page_layout which shows that all of a-z, A-Z and 0-9 are above 127. EBCDIC was always an 8-bit encoding, so the basic alnum chars did not need to be in the low 7 bits.

So for a system using EBCDIC your implementation would give `isascii('\u0085')` as `true`, whereas a system using UTF-8 or most other encodings that overlap with ASCII can't even represent `\u0085` in a single char. More problematically, for EBCDIC your function gives `isascii('a')` as `false`, and `isascii('0')` etc.

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/evK3ErErT

Answer (score -2):

The [meeting minutes](http://www.opengroup.org/austin/docs/austin_317.html) have this to say:

> isascii: mark obsolete. Application Usage should note that this cannot be used portably in a localized application.

Comment: Which doesn't really tell us anything, does it? He's asking *why* it cannot be used portably in a localized application.

Comment: It's still good to have someone cite the original source of the decision. This might be the best we can get from posix as to the original reasoning.